# sudo apt-get install skype?

Tags: apt, software-installation, skype

### Running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I tryed to install skype.

### In terminal:

```
 sudo sh -c ‘echo “deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner” >>
 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list’

 sudo apt-get update

 sudo apt-get install skype
```

E: Unable to locate package skype

```
 sudo apt-get -f install

 sudo apt-get install skype
```

E: Unable to locate package skype

*So, no skype... How do I get skype?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in there:

```
$ apt-cache policy skype
skype:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
  Version table:
     4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 0
        500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner amd64 Packages
```

Looking at your post, it looks like you've copied in some curly-quotes. These aren't interpreted by Bash in the same way so they're probably not working as intended. I'd use this instead:

```
echo "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it. I'm not certain how to distinguish between different types of command line or when which is appropriate, but I suppose I'll ensure to use Bash in terminal from now on.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood me. The curly quote characters you were using (I suspect copied from a Wordpress blog) `‘` and `“` are syntactically different from what they were supposed to be: `'` and `"` respectively.

Comment: You're right I don't understand. I've started working through a Bash tutorial. I really don't know much, but I think I understand now the curly-quote is a literally curly quote mark. The first command line you entered made the difference. 
So, Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In the Software Centre there's a skype client. It has worked for me. Alternatively, you can get the .deb file from skype.com and run it by the SC.

Comment: Neither of those options are working for me at the moment. It seems like Linux still has a long way to go before I make the switch from Windows once and for all.